How to get the additional claims (injected by client) in confidential client token using MSAL with ADFS?
Trying to authenticate server app via confidential client grant type with ADFS (v2022) and want to send some claims in authentication request to get back in the client token.
Came across this below link but it seems the API doesn't work with ADFS. Wanted to know Is there any alternative or any way I can achieve this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/acquiring-tokens/web-apps-apis/confidential-client-assertions#withclientclaims.
Here is what I've tried from Microsoft.Identity.Client (v4.60.1 for net48):
IConfidentialClientApplication appBuilder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithCertificate(certificate)
                .WithAdfsAuthority(authority)
                .WithClientClaims(certificate, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "additional_claim", "additional_val" } }, true)
                .Build();

var auth_result = await appBuilder.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

Expecting that the token received in auth_result should contain claim "additional_claim" with value "additional_val".
